# Reference PHP Sub-Arrays by Key

Tags: php, arrays, xml, json

I am playing with PHP 5.4 to process some data that is returned from an HTTP API.  The data comes back in XML format which I then convert to an array using the following:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($resp);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
```

This gives me the data in array form (if there is a better way to do this, please tell me!).  The result is the following sample array:

```
array (
  '@attributes' =>
  array (
    'status' => 'success',
    'code' => '19',
  ),
  'result' =>
  array (
    '@attributes' =>
    array (
      'total-count' => '1',
      'count' => '1',
    ),
    'user' =>
    array (
      'entry' =>
      array (
        0 =>
        array (
          '@attributes' =>
          array (
            'name' => 'chris',
          ),
          'phash' => 's98djf384jr0oq8jf8j3948jfw',
        ),
        1 =>
        array (
          '@attributes' =>
          array (
            'name' => 'test',
          ),
          'phash' => '9a8sdfu9n2308ja8fj34ojr9a0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to properly reference various elements of the array.  I have tried referencing by index like echo $arr[0][0] but that doesn't return anything and I can't find out how to reference sub-arrays by key.

Comment: Have you tried: `$arr['@attributes']['status']`?

Comment: how can you refer it by `$arr[0][0]` it doesn't have 0 key right/ so refer with existing keys like `$arr['@attributes']['code']`

Comment: Your array doesbt have a 0 key. Us result and user keus. Than call the 0 key.

Comment: I'm just learning PHP now and I knew it had to be something simple like that!  Thanks!

Comment: foreach($array as $key => $value){}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is clearly documented in the PHP manual.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Arrays in PHP are key/value pairs. When the key is not specified PHP will use numeric indexes.

You can access the values as `$arr['@attributes']['status']`

To check if a key exists you can use `isset($arr['@attributes'])` or `array_key_exists('@attributes',$arr)`.

To enumerate

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) { .... }
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks.  I did look at that page but I missed that section.  More coffee needed!